# Rails cycle helper function isn't working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I use the cycle helper function inside a loop to cycle between two CSS classes but it doesn't work. It always chooses the first CSS class in each iteration.

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="<%= cycle("left-animate", "right-animate") + ' col-sm-6' %>"><%= image_tag project.screen_shot %></div>
    <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm"></div>
    <div class="<%= cycle("right-animate", "left-animate") + ' col-sm-6 col-md-5' %>">
      <h4><%= project.title %></h4>
      <%= raw project.description %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Rails version is 5.2 and Ruby version is 2.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing "name" parameter. Can you use it like this?

```
 <% @projects.each do |project| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="<%= cycle("left-animate", "right-animate, name:'image') + ' col-sm-6' %>"><%= image_tag project.screen_shot %></div>
            <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm"></div>
            <div class="<%= cycle("right-animate", "left-animate",name:'summary') + ' col-sm-6 col-md-5' %>">
              <h4><%= project.title %></h4>
              <%= raw project.description %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining two cycles with the same [implicit] name, so they're cancelling each other out.

It sounds like you might want to use `current_cycle` in the second instance, to re-use the value from the preceding call.